# c3dl getPosition() returns a float32array, what does it represent?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I created an model duck and want to track its position i.e x,y,z value, below is my code. However, it returned `[Object Float32Array]` , I have no idea what this presents, how to interpret it?

```
duck.getPosition().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `duck.getPosition().toString()` use `duck.getPosition()`.
`toString()` does not output the actual content of the typed array.